# If-else statements not working for model

Tags: java, swing, if-statement

What I want

On a JPanel, I have a JButton and a JTextArea. Upon pressing JButton, certain text has to be printed inside the JTextArea. This certain text is determined by if-else statements. Conditions of if-else are based on an integer variable R.

Basically its a survey like question-answer thing I'm trying to make. I use the R to record answers from user. When a user clicks a choice, the value of R gets updated.

I use a String variable yourphone. If the value of R in the end is eg 120, then yourphone gets updated to a string eg. Xperia Z.

This final JPanel I'm talking about is where I display result. Total value of R is used in if-else statements.

Structure

I initiate variable like this

```
int R=0;
String yourphone;
```

Here is the code of JPanel

```
final JPanel result = new JPanel();
        result.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        getContentPane().add(result, "name_17130054294139");
        result.setLayout(null);


        final JTextArea txtrphoneresult = new JTextArea();
        txtrphoneresult.setRows(5);
        txtrphoneresult.setBounds(68, 84, 285, 148);
        result.add(txtrphoneresult);

        JButton btnShowResult = new JButton("Show Result");
        btnShowResult.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                txtrphoneresult.setText(yourphone + R);

            }
        });
        btnShowResult.setBounds(68, 29, 103, 32);
        result.add(btnShowResult);
```

Here are what my if-else statements look like

```
if(R==1749)
        {
            yourphone = "Galaxy Mega 5.8";
        }
if(R==1726)
        {
            yourphone = "Xperia Z";
        }
else
            {
                    yourphone = "NO Result";
            }
```

Problem

Upon execution, no matter what the result is always "NO Result" which means that value of R is always something else than my predicted totals. But that cannot be right because I print the value of R alongside

```
txtrphoneresult.setText(yourphone + R);
```

And the result output is "NO Result 1749". Which is impossible because it indicates that value of R is updated. And if its 1749 then the output should be "Galaxy Mega 5.8". I don't know why its takes output of yourphone from the else statement when the if condition is clearly met.

Answer (score 6):

You need to add `else` after first if:

```
if(R==1749) {
    yourphone = "Galaxy Mega 5.8";
} else if(R==1726) {
    yourphone = "Xperia Z";
} else {
    yourphone = "NO Result";
}
```

Otherwise, `yourphone` will be `"NO Result"` even if `R == 1749`.

Comment: I tried that. It still isn't working. Showing "No Result 1749".

Comment: Did you try debugging it?

Comment: I'm at a very beginner level with Java. So I don't know how to. Can you please link me somewhere helpful?

Comment: Where do you set the value of R?

Comment: Never mind, it got solved. I put the if else statements inside the ActionListener of the JButton and boom!!! It worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
if(R==1749)
  yourphone = "Galaxy Mega 5.8";
else if(R==1726)
  yourphone = "Xperia Z";
else
  yourphone = "NO Result";

this will solve your problem;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your nested `if-else` statement is not correct. `If-else` condition should be

```
if(R==1749){
    yourphone = "Galaxy Mega 5.8";
}
else if(R==1726){
    yourphone = "Xperia Z";
}
else{
     yourphone = "NO Result";
}
```

Comment: I tried that. It still isn't working. Showing "No Result 1749"